# iOS Device Enrollment with Self-Developed MDM?

Tags: java, ios, iphone, mdm

I am in the process of trying to develop a really simple proof-of-concept iOS MDM that will allow for OTA enrollment of iOS devices.  This isn't meant to be some MobileIron replacement or anything.  It's really just a learning exercise.  I am developing my code in Java, with JAX-RS for the RESTful service endpoints.

At this point, I am able to it a URL (http://myhost/enroll) from my iOS that will return an enrollment response to kickoff the device enrollment process.  The response returned looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Inc//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <dict>
            <key>URL</key>
            <string>https://myhost/profile</string>
            <key>DeviceAttributes</key>
            <array>
                <string>UDID</string>
                <string>IMEI</string>
                <string>ICCID</string>
                <string>VERSION</string>
                <string>PRODUCT</string>
            </array>
            <key>Challenge</key>
            <string>MySuperSecureChallenge</string>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>Example Inc.</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>fdb376e5-b5bb-4d8c-829e-e90865f990c9</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.example.mobileconfig.profile-service</string>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>Enter device into the Example Inc encrypted profile service</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Once my device receives this payload, it takes me to the Settings app and prompts me to install the profile.  When I click "Install", it performs an HTTP `POST` to another URL (http://myhost/profile) and includes the attributes I requested in the response from /enroll.

My `/profile` endpoint is able to successfully extract the signed response from my iOS device, which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CHALLENGE</key>
        <string>MySuperSecureChallenge</string>
        <key>IMEI</key>
        <string>__MY_IMEI__</string>
        <key>PRODUCT</key>
        <string>iPhone10,4</string>
        <key>UDID</key>
        <string>__MY_UDID__</string>
        <key>VERSION</key>
        <string>15B202</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

My question is:  now what??  I've found [example payloads like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/ConfigurationProfileExamples/ConfigurationProfileExamples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH4-SW6) (from Apple) that show how to do SCEP enrollment.  However, I don't want to do SCEP for this simple proof-of-concept.  Is there something else I can return at this stage?  If so, what should the response contain and look like?  I haven't found any documentation outlining what should be returned by my `/profile` endpoint if I'm *not* using SCEP, so I'm a little stuck.

**UPDATE:**  I found some resources online that imply that I need to either use SCEP or provide a PKCS#12-formatted certificate in the payload.  So, I have updated the return value of the `/profile` to look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Inc//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Configuration</string>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>PayloadContent</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Challenge</key>
                    <string>MyChallengeGoesHere</string>
                </dict>
                <key>PayloadDescription</key>
                <string>Provides device encryption identity</string>
                <key>PayloadUUID</key>
                <string>fd8a6b9e-0fed-406f-9571-8ec98722b713</string>
                <key>PayloadType</key>
                <string>com.apple.security.pkcs12</string>
                <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
                <string>Cert Test</string>
                <key>PayloadVersion</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
                <string>Example, Inc.</string>
                <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.example.profileservice.webclip</string>
                <key>PayloadContent</key>
                <string>__MY_BASE64_ENCODED_PKCS12_CERT__</string>
                <key>Password</key>
                <string>__MY_CERT_PASSWORD__</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I'm returning this value back to the client, but when I click `Install` on my iOS device, I get an error saying:

> Profile Installation Failed A connection to the server could not be
>   established.

Now, I know that communication isn't an issue, because I see the connection to `/profile` in my logs and debugger.  Is there something else I'm missing?  Does the profile need to be digitally signed?  If so, what format is it?  Which certificate should I be using to sign it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After LOTS of trial and error, I have finally figured out what the issue was for this profile.  I was missing a couple of parameters:  `PayloadIdentifier` and `PayloadUUID`.  Further, the value for the `PayloadContent` parameter containing my base64-encoded certificate should be `data`, not `string`.  So, my new profile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Inc//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Configuration</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>9f93912b-5fd2-4455-99fd-13b9a47b4581</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>org.example.mymdm</string>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>PayloadType</key>
                <string>com.apple.security.pkcs12</string>
                <key>PayloadUUID</key>
                <string>f78c5002-3907-4f67-b631-d41c44283628</string>
                <key>PayloadVersion</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.mymdm.cert</string>
                <key>Password</key>
                <string>__MY_CERT_PASSWORD__</string>
                <key>PayloadContent</key>
                <data>__MY_BASE64_ENCODED_P12__</data>
              </dict>
          </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Once I made these changes, I was able to successfully install the profile on my iOS device.